# Formatting a date fetched using REST ajax call from SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date, sharepoint

I'm creating a simple table using data fetched from SharePoint. everything works perfectly in Google Chrome, but I'm having some issues with Internet Explorer 11. the date is pulled from SharePoint in this format:

```
2015-03-17T00:00:00
```

The portion of the code that deals with this is:

```
var dateReceived = data.d.results[i].DateReceived;
if (dateReceived  !== null){dateReceived = new Date(parseInt(dateReceived.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10)).toLocaleString('en-US', {
         year: 'numeric',
         month: 'numeric',
         day: '2-digit'
     });}
     else {dateReceived = "";}
```

As I mentioned this works perfectly in Chrome and the date display in the MM/DD/YYYY format. But in IE shows like this: "Monday, March 16, 2015 8:00:00 PM". What am I doing wrong here? I could give moment.js a try, but I feel that it is not necessary to add it for just this when it is already partially working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `moment.js` , or maybe trying to change de format in the nav like this: http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/general-support/18251d1363139622t-change-format-date-modified-explorer-dt.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Explorer handles date objects differently than other browsers. Without going into unnecessary details, why are you not just creating a new `Date` object of the return value from SharePoint, and then convert it to your desired locale format?

The code below

```
var date = new Date("2015-03-17T00:00:00");
var formatDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric" });
console.log("Formated date is: " + formatDate);
```

outputs

`Formated date is: ‎3‎/‎17‎/‎2015`

in IE11.

Comment: Daniel, how to compare this date with todays; date ? i wannna check the datefield value from splist and todays date

Answer (score 2):

Add `.replace(/[^ -~]/g,'')` toLocaleString for IE.

The code will look like

```
var date = new Date("2015-03-17T00:00:00");
var formatDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric" }).replace(/[^ -~]/g,''); 
console.log("Formated date is: " + formatDate);
```

output

```
Formated date is: ‎3‎/‎17‎/‎2015
```